# How can I cache queries in sqlalchemy just like I do it in mysql by using SQL_CACHE keyword?

Tags: mysql, cache, query-cache

I want to cache sqlalchemy,i have discovered that using keyword SQL_CACHE in mysql can be helpful in caching queries on demand.
But how do i do it in sqlalchemy ?
Is it possible ?

Comment: The Query cache is not that useful.  If you have slow queries; let's see them and work on speeding them up.  Sometimes it is as simple as adding a composite index.

Comment: Ya you are right about it . But i want to know how do i do it in sqlalchemy ?Is it possible ?

Comment: <cynicism>Another case of 3rd party software getting in the way.</cynicism>

Answer (score 0):

You need use a [prefix_with](https://docs.ruanjiadeng.com/sqlalchemy/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.prefix_with).
For example, this:

```py
query = session.query(User.name).prefix_with('SQL_CACHE')
```

would render:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE users.name AS users_name FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question, but deserves an answer.

You have to set the [query_cache_type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type).

Here are the values and their meaning

- `0 or OFF` : Do not cache results in or retrieve results from the query cache. Note that this does not deallocate the query cache buffer. To do that, you should set query_cache_size to 0.
- `1 or ON` : Cache all cacheable query results except for those that begin with SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE.
- `2 or DEMAND` Cache results only for cacheable queries that begin with SELECT SQL_CACHE.

By default, query_cache_type is 0 (Cache Nothing).

You can run this to cache every `SELECT` that does not have `SQL_NO_CACHE` directive in your session:

```
SET query_cache_type = 1;
```

You can run this to cache every `SELECT` that has the `SQL_CACHE` directive in your session:

```
SET query_cache_type = 2;
```

If you want it set globally, then run

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 2;
```

Then add that to the my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_type = 2
```

**PLEASE NOTE THIS TOTALLY GOES AWAY IN MySQL 8.0 !!!**

This answer is only good for MySQL 5.7 and prior, also older MariaDB versions

### What About SQLAlchemy ???

Since you want the caching on demand, please set [query_cache_type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type) to 2.

Then you can run

```
query = session.query(User.name).prefix_with('SQL_CACHE')
```